# Select specific regions of .shp file using Geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, shapefile, geopandas

I have a .shp file that contains limits of oceans and seas. But, instead of plotting all of them, I'm interested only in 6. Geopandas creates something similar a dataframe (let's call it "df"), just like Pandas. Is it possible to create a new dataframe ("df1") that would have just those selected areas of "df"?

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gp

tes = gp.read_file(r'your\path\World_Seas_IHO_v1\World_Seas.shp')

tes1 = tes[(tes.NAME == "North Pacific Ocean"),
           (tes.NAME == "South Pacific Ocean")]

tes1.plot()

plt.show()
plt.ion()
```

When I run this, "tes1" gets an error:

"Series objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed."

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(tes.NAME == "North Pacific Ocean"), (tes.NAME == "South Pacific Ocean")` is a `tuple` of boolean series.  You can't pass this as an indexer.  You want to use bitwise or `|` to combine the boolean series and then use the result to slice the dataframe.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gp

tes = gp.read_file(r'your\path\World_Seas_IHO_v1\World_Seas.shp')

tes1 = tes[(tes.NAME == "North Pacific Ocean") |
           (tes.NAME == "South Pacific Ocean")]

tes1.plot()

plt.show()
plt.ion()
```

Or you could use `isin`

```
tes = gp.read_file(r'your\path\World_Seas_IHO_v1\World_Seas.shp')

tes1 = tes[tes.NAME.isin(['North Pacific Ocean', 'South Pacific Ocean'])]

tes1.plot()

plt.show()
plt.ion()
```

[image]

Comment: Hey piRSquared. I tried and what I got was:


Empty GeoDataFrame
Columns: [Gazetteer_, ID, NAME, geometry]
Index = [ ]

Comment: I need the actual shape file.  Where can I get it?

Comment: http://www.marineregions.org/downloads.php > IHO Sea Areas > Version 1 (2005) > Sea Areas Shapefile (1,733kb)

Comment: My apologies, it was or, not and.